# Limit CPU usage of fwrite operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, cpu-usage, fwrite

I'm developing a program with several threads that manages the streaming from several cameras. I have to write every raw images on SSD disk. I'm using `fwrite` to put the image in a binary file. Something like:

```
FILE* output;
output = fopen(fileName, "wb");
fwrite(imageData, imageSize, 1, output);
fclose(output);
```

The procedure seems to runs fast enough to save all images with the given cameras throughput. The problem is that the save procedure is CPU consuming, and I start to have sync issues when the save process is enabled, due to the CPU usage of the save threads.

Is there any way to reduce the CPU load of fwrite operations? Like playing with buffering, better DMA settings, ...?

Thanks!

MIX

-- UPDATE 1

Forgetting the multithreading software, here is a simple file writer software:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const unsigned int TOT_DATA = 1280*2*960;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage:\n");
    printf("  %s totWrite\n\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  char* imageData;
  FILE* output;
  char fileName[256];
  unsigned int totWrite;

  totWrite = atoi(argv[1]);
  imageData = new char[TOT_DATA];

  printf("Write imageData[%u] on file %u times.\n", TOT_DATA, totWrite);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < totWrite; i++)
  {
    sprintf(fileName, "image_%06u.raw", i);
    output = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    fwrite(imageData, TOT_DATA, 1, output);
    fclose(output);
  }
  printf("DONE!\n");  

  delete [] imageData;

  return 0;
}
```

A char buffer will be created, and it will be written on file `totWrite` times. No overwrites, since each cycle writes on a new file. (of course, one have to remove files written by previous run...)

Running `top` (I'm on Linux) while the program is running I see that ~50% of the CPU (that means 50% of one of the 4 cores) is used. I suppose fwrite is the bottleneck regarding the CPU usage since it is the "slower" operation in the cycle, so the one "more probably" running when `top` update its stats. Even "more probable" if `TOT_DATA` will be increased, say, 100 times.

Any further consideration about what can reduce CPU usage in such program?

Comment: Are you sure that fwrite consumes much CPU? It should only be blocking because the hard disc is not so fast. Nevertheless you could try OS level functions like open/write or CreateFile/WriteFile.

Comment: Don't open/close the file around each write.

Comment: @Mat It's not certain that that's a problem - it could be that the `fwrite` is all writes that should go to the file.

Comment: I wouldn't generally have multiple threads writing to disk.

Comment: Yeah, just have the 'file write' thread flush/close/reopen the file when its input queue is empty.

Comment: Can you explain to us how you concluded that the CPU usage of `fwrite` operations was the problem? That seems very hard to believe. Also, are you using a platform and filesystem that supports TRIM? Is it enabled? It may be erasing that's the problem.

Comment: @skyking: It is _certainly_ a problem, Mat is entirely right. Closing the descriptor means _flushing_. Which means many small writes. Depending on what resolution those images are, writes may be smaller than SSD allocation blocks. So yes, writing 500 frames in one go vs opening/closing a descriptor 500 times may be very significant (in addition to the very non-trivial amount of CPU work that the operating system has to do for `open`).

Comment: As you can see in the updated source code, each frame is written on a different file, so what Mat said is not the problem. Although I agree with him when working in "append" mode.

Comment: @Damon As I wrote - it depends. Yes you have to flush when closing, but you will have to do that anyway eventually, but if that write is all you're going to write then no - there aren't going to be 500 times opening/closing, just one. Where is it written that there is more than one block that is written? How can you then say that it's certainly a problem? Note that the updated code includes one 2 MiB block of data that is written to the file so it's reasonable to assume that it's not 500 tiny bits that are written. In addition the file is truncated so I'd assume that there's no more than that.

Comment: One file per frame is a nightmare scenario, both for the disk and for the operating system. The OS must traverse the fs and check access rights, must walk through the directory to be sure the new name is not already taken, allocate a new inode and blocks. Create/write/close alltogether means writing to at least three independent storage blocks (inode, bitmap, data) and in at least two of these, you suffer considerable write amplification on a SSD because when you write 256 bytes for an inode, about 511.75kB must be moved (same for changing 2-3 bytes in the bitmap).

Comment: @Damon, well, awfully that's what I -have- to do. I can't interlace frames, save video, ... Need to save each frame. Note that I always write around 2MB of data, so (maybe) the inode size is not a problem. Maybe I can optimize the file system. I'm using btrfs without any formatting options. Any idea about how to optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider playing with DMA settings you're way out of the scope of the standard C library. It will be nowhere near portable - and then you don't have any benefits of using portable functions.

The first step you probably should use (after you've confirmed that it's CPU that is the bottleneck) is to use lower level functions like for example `open`/`write` (or whatever your OS calls them).

Basically what can happen with `fwrite` is that the program first copies the data to another place in memory (the `FILE*` buffer) before actually writing the data to disc. This operation certainly is CPU bound and if data transfer by the CPU is slower than the data transfer to the SSD it could be a case where CPU power is consumed for no good reason.

Also one should note that using multiple threads have it's drawbacks. First if it were not an SSD multiple threads writing to disk could result in redundant head movements which is not bad, but even SSD may suffer somewhat as you might fragment the layout of the data.

There's also a problem in loading the entire file as you seem to do in the example, especially if you do it in multiple threads. It will simply consume a lot of memory (which could result in that swapping is required). If possible you should write the data to the file as the data arrives.